# What is list of Prometheus labels and variables that can be used in alert template

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am writing some checks for Prometheus, and I would like to find out, which variables I may use in templates. I am using `$labels.container`, but `$labels.service` and `$labels.instance` does not work. For example, I am using instance in prometheus queries, but I am not able to use it in template. How can I find out all labels, or other variables I can use in template? I implemented own exporter written in python that controls which containers in docker swarm keep restarting.

I am new with Prometheus and Alertmanager and documentation does not looks very clear according to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels that are available are the labels that are returned by the alerting query.
So if your query looks like:

```
sum ( something_here ) > 0
```

you will have *no* labels available.

If you have

```
sum by (label_foo)(...) > 0
```

then you will only have label_foo available.

If you do:

```
metric_name
```

Then you'll get all the labels that are available on metric_name metric.

Just execute your alerting query directly in prometheus (making sure query does return something - remove any threshold etc.) and you'll see the labels available.

Comment: Thank you, I was encountering missing labels because of `by` in my querries.

Comment: How to get the actual label_foo that triggered the alert? E.g for an alert of the form `sum by (label_foo) (...) > 0`, how can I access `label_foo` that was triggered? Something like `{{ label_foo }}`?

Comment: @exAres use `{{ $labels.label_foo }}` in your template